# How can I create a new column of binary values from my TfidfVectorizer sparse matrix?

Tags: python, data-mining, data-cleaning

I currently have a sparse matrix object of TfidfVectorizer which is of 1000 length. Right now it is displayed like this:

```
(0, 833)    0.0125811983337
(0, 273)    0.017346359033
(0, 602)    0.0150870927018
(0, 336)    0.123313011424
(0, 921)    0.117637963781
(0, 387)    0.0255455514666
(0, 151)    0.0402355794242
(0, 959)    0.0752284252869
(0, 862)    0.0183447833135
(0, 119)    0.0142898118798
(0, 289)    0.156947194082
(0, 820)    0.484668345462
(0, 95)     0.265061750957
(0, 351)    0.0958489700942
(0, 192)    0.148380396091
(0, 104)    0.104538714112
(0, 558)    0.137032224303
(0, 692)    0.0121762757783
```

and so on.

I would like to create a new column that has a list of length 1000 with binary values in which we have a 1 on the 1st row (index 0) and the $833^{rd}$ item (column 833 which represents 0,833 0.0125811) and so on...

Much like:

```
column 1 2 3 4 5 ... 833 ... 1000

row 0 [0 0 0 0 0 ...  1 ....   0]
```

And I would like to do this for every row for which sparse matrix has been calculated. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var = (0,833)
new_var = np.zeros(1000)
for i in var:
    new_var[i] = 1
```

I would need your sparse matrix datatype to give you a more precise answer.

Comment: sparse = TfidfVectorizer(max_features = 1000).fit_transform(dataframe['column1']). sparse is the sparse matrix object that is created !